# How to show all false outputs in a circuit?

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, circuits

I have 3 input variables and the output for all 8 possible combinations is 0 (false). When making a circuit, how would I show this using gates or no gates at all? Thanks!

Comment: You mean, how do you draw a signal that is always false? I'd just write 0 or F and draw a line to it, probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $A \land \lnot A$ is always False, no matter whether $A$ is True or False.

Answer (score 0):

First you can write down the [truth table](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table?wprov=sfla1) of your circuit, in this case it will be entirely composed of $0$s.
Then you will build up a [Boolean expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra?wprov=sfla1) in the form you prefer (if you have no limitations) which reproduces the behavior (relation input/output) observed in the truth table.

Note that every *operator* of your *boolean expression* correspond to a logic gate:

$\land$ = *AND*

$\lor$ = *OR*

$\neg$ = *NOT*

$\oplus$ = *XOR*